# Significance test for PMCC

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance

149 students each sat two tests. My null hypothesis is that the product-moment correlation coefficient is 1, because each test should be an accurate indicator of current attainment. The actual PMCC for the data is 0.912152856.

Please could you show (and explain) how to test if this is a significant result?

Comment: I see where you are coming from, but if the underlying correlation were exactly 1, that implies exact linear relationship and it's hard for me to see how there is an associated sampling distribution for sample correlation. That case is not parallel to there being a bivariate Gaussian for which the real correlation is exactly 0 but sample correlations will vary. For your results I get  95% confidence limits of 0.880 and 0.936 (Fisher z method). FWIW, I advise against quoting correlations to 9 d.p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think through what you mean by "significant".  Often in statistics this has a technical meaning in the context "significant evidence by which we can dismiss a null hypothesis".  Sometimes an implicit null hypothesis in this case would be that the true correlation is zero and the apparent relationship is due to random chance, and hence we are looking for significant evidence to dismiss that possibility.  You certainly have evidence to dismiss this possibility, and this is the test you will get if you just google for "correlation coefficient significance tests".

However, the fact is that you aren't interested in r=0 as a null hypothesis.  Perhaps you really are interested in r=1 as a null hypothesis and you want to test whether the real world is consistent with that.  Well, you do have significant evidence against that, without conducting any fancy tests.  If the real relationship were a perfect 1, there would be no deviation between the two tests no matter how small, and clearly you have some such deviation.  So if you want you can say you have significant evidence against your hypothesis that the two tests are perfectly correlated.

However this seems an unfairly high expectation of two tests - that people get exactly the same score on each, with no randomness even for the chance of having an off day on one rather than the other.  So you are left with a judgement call that needs to be based on subject matter and contextual knowledge.  What is the acceptable minimum for a correlation between the two - above zero, but below 1?  Then I would suggest framing your null hypothesis as "the correlation between the two tests is at this level or lower".  And you are looking for significant evidence to dismiss that null hyothesis, leaving you with the conclusion that the relationship is higher than that threshold.

The same tests we just googled can test against a null hypothesis of any level/s of correlation coefficient, although they normally default to testing a null hypothesis of no relation.

In the above I have assumed (from the way you worded "my hypothesis") that you are interested in proving the tests are ok, not that they are inadequate.  That is why I have expressed the null hypothesis in those terms.